# Odoo tree View for wizard in saas server

Tags: tree, odoo

I want to show the fields that i mentioned in the tree string when there are no records in my tree view instead of showing

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sample_tree_view">
        <field name="name">Bizu</field>
        <field name="model">Bizu.test</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml"
            <tree string="Bizu" default_order="name">
                <field name="code" />
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="status" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record> 

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_sample">
        <field name="name">Bizu</field>
        <field name="res_model">sample.test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                Click here to create a new sample Record.
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

// How to increase the size of the column in tree view in odoo//

Answer (score 0):

Your first question, for showing a message (e.g. list of fields or any other data) you should write them in help field, replace `Click here to create a new sample Record.` with your text, maybe something about fields)
And your second question, it is not possible. Field with is set dynamically in the browser.